# Running a Capistrano deployment task with AWS user-data

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, capistrano3

My scenario : I have an AMI with a `deploy/` folder that contains the capistrano files that I use to deploy a production application on localhost

I was planning to use a user-data script from an Autoscaling group, to deploy the most recent version of the server each time the group scales up and spawns a new machine

The script must be ran as the user ubuntu

Here is my user-data

```
cd /home/ubuntu/
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket-config/production/rails/startup_script.sh ./startup_script.sh --region my-region
chmod +x ./startup_script.sh
chown ubuntu:ubuntu ./startup_script.sh
su - ubuntu -c "./startup_script.sh"
```

This startup script contains

```
cd /home/ubuntu/deploy/
git pull
git checkout production
cap aws_localhost_production deploy
```

I run into a weird error message during the `cap deploy`, and I didn't find a lot of references on google about this one

> NoMethodError: undefined method `winsize' for nil:NilClass

Here is the full stack

```
The deploy has failed with an error: undefined method `winsize' for nil:NilClass
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/airbrussh-1.0.1/lib/airbrussh/console.rb:61:in `console_width': undefined method `winsize' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/airbrussh-1.0.1/lib/airbrussh/console.rb:26:in `print_line'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/airbrussh-1.0.1/lib/airbrussh/capistrano/tasks.rb:77:in `each_line'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/airbrussh-1.0.1/lib/airbrussh/capistrano/tasks.rb:77:in `error_line'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/airbrussh-1.0.1/lib/airbrussh/capistrano/tasks.rb:42:in `deploy_failed'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/airbrussh-1.0.1/lib/airbrussh/capistrano.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/airbrussh-1.0.1/lib/airbrussh/rake/context.rb:55:in `execute'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capistrano-3.5.0/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:15:in `invoke'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capistrano-3.5.0/lib/capistrano/dsl/task_enhancements.rb:56:in `exit_deploy_because_of_exception'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capistrano-3.5.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:73:in `exit_because_of_exception'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `rescue in standard_exception_handling'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capistrano-3.5.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:14:in `run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capistrano-3.5.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/cap:23:in `load'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that `winsize` involves detecting the size of the shell window in which the application is running. Try adding `set :format, :pretty` to your `config/deploy.rb`. It will tell it to stop using the Airbrusshed formatter and default to a more verbose option.